# How to set order to Gerrit Trigger builds in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, gerrit-trigger

My Gerrit Server events are integrated to Jenkins (via Gerrit Trigger plugin) in such a way that 3 different Jenkins builds are triggered (say A,B,C) when Code Review +2 is received on a Gerrit PatchSet.

Currently any of the A, B or C builds are getting triggered first, there is no definite order. My requirement is to ensure that job A is triggered first, followed by B and C.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Note: I can't setup a dependency job (say A->B->C) since I have many executors configured for this job. Setting a serial dependency would not utilise idle executors.

Answer (score 0):

Add a quiet period to the B and C builds.

In Configuration > General > Advanced... > Quiet period